# Kontakt Beacon foreground/background scan in multiple activity?

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, beacon

I am using Kontakt beacons in my android app.I want my app to scan beacon in foreground and background in all the activities of my app. Currently it is working with the only activity in which i implement it.I am using there Kontakt sample app as reference. Can any one tell me how can i make it work without reusing same code in all activities?

Answer (score 0):

Use [broadcast receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)
A broadcast receiver (short receiver) is an Android component which allows you to register for system or application events. All registered receivers for an event are notified by the Android runtime once this event happens.

Answer (score 0):

The free and open source [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) has support for this feature out of the box.  It will scan for beacons at phone bootup and give a callback to your app's central Application class when beacons are detected.  From there you can make calls to any activities that are running.

You can see an example of how to do this in the Starting an App in the Background section of the [code samples](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html).  This is also set up for you in the [Reference Application.](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference)

Note that if you decide to go this route, you will need to configure the library with a `BeaconParser` that matches the format of your Kontakt beacons.  This is only one line of code.